# Showing posts live during a date range

Tags: entries, postdate

I've tried to follow a ton of other articles posted on Stackoverflow for showing posts between 2 dates. I just can't seem to get it working and I keep getting an error of: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean

```
{% set startDate = now | date_modify('first day of ' ~ qFilter) %}
{% set endDate = startDate | date_modify('+ 1 month') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').postDate('<= startDate').expiryDate('>= endDate') %}
```

(qFilter is a url param: eg "May")

I'm trying to show posts that were live during a certain month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a string `<= startDate` to the field parameter, but you actually want it to be a string `<= 2016-01-01`, which you can get by concatenationg the `<=` string with the datetime variable. So change your parameters like so:

`postDate('<= ' ~ startDate)` instead of
`postDate('<= startDate')`